# does kafka have a async request/response java api?

Tags: apache-kafka

We would prefer to use an asynchronous request/response like so on the producer

```
private class MyCallback implements ResponseCallback {
    public void response(Response r) {
        //handle failure or success.  If success, ack the upstream kafka
    }
}
producer.send(request, callback);
```

The only thing I have seen is setting producer.type to asynch but the call is just an asynchronous request without waiting for any response...

```
producer.send(request);
```

This unfortunately forces me to synchronous which means under load, my threads waiting on kafka could start to slow things down when I would much prefer to just slam kafka with a bunch of requests and receive responses while I keep sending requests.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is nice work in progress in Kafka that will introduce asynch calling patters, check this out: [Consumer](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-dev/201402.mbox/%3CCAOG_4QYBHwyi0xN=HL1FpnRTkVfJZX14uJFntfT3nn_Mw3%2BXgQ@mail.gmail.com%3E) and [Producer](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/kafka-dev/201401.mbox/%3CCAOeJiJhr8DOhOVX8C7GcqtBQj-0RZmohqz_patNP=QarRjb9UA@mail.gmail.com%3E)

For the time being, you could use standard Callable/Executors and add callbacks to them using Google Guava's excellent [ListenableFuture](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained). You could also explore [Hystrix](https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix) by Netflix for more (complex and flexible) calling patterns.

Answer (score 0):

Kafka has added asynchronous send with a callback. See the documentation [here](https://kafka.apache.org/090/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/producer/KafkaProducer.html).

**producer.send(ProducerRecord record, Callback callback)**

> Asynchronously send a record to a topic and invoke the provided callback when the send has been acknowledged.
>   The send is asynchronous and this method will return immediately once the record has been stored in the buffer of records waiting to be sent. This allows sending many records in parallel without blocking to wait for the response after each one.